# Self invoking function in javascript does not seem to work

Tags: javascript

After reading about self invoking functions I decided to take it for a spin, wondering why this example code does not invoke after it has loaded.

```
var App = App || {};

(function() {
    'use strict';

    App.MainUtility = {
         sayHello: function() {
           alert('Hello from the main utility');
        }
    };
    return App.MainUtility;
})();
```

Is there a chance that I am not understanding something properly?

Comment: What does/doesn't happen that surprises/disappoints you?

Comment: I think in alert pop up, message is given in double quotes....

Comment: @Ahmed no, single- and double- quotes both create strings with exactly the same semantics.

Comment: That's new to me... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case your self executing function has done 2 things

1. Defined a property named `MainUtility` on `App`
2. Returned the property

At no point was it invoked hence nothing is expected to be displayed.  You can display it though by adding the following line in place of `return`

```
App.MainUtility.sayHello();
```